# Sort PHP Custom Data Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort this list by next upcoming date to furthest away date. I've tried so many things i cant count.

What would be the right way to sort this list?

```
array(13) {
  [9]=>
  string(16) "Jun 30 - Tuesday"
  [8]=>
  string(16) "Jun 23 - Tuesday"
  [10]=>
  string(16) "Jul 07 - Tuesday"
  [11]=>
  string(17) "Jun 25 - Thursday"
  [12]=>
  string(17) "Jul 02 - Thursday"
  [7]=>
  string(15) "Jul 06 - Monday"
  [6]=>
  string(18) "Jul 01 - Wednesday"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "Jun 26 - Friday"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Jul 05 - Sunday"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "Jul 03 - Friday"
  [4]=>
  string(18) "Jun 24 - Wednesday"
  [5]=>
  string(15) "Jun 29 - Monday"
  [0]=>
  string(15) "Jun 28 - Sunday"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might as well use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Using the first example on the usort docs page as a template, you could do something like this:

```
function compare_dates( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime( $a ) < strtotime( $b ) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort( $your_array_of_dates, 'compare_dates' );
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your way doesn't seem to sort it correctly. I've posted an answer above that does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I think.

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    $a = explode(" - ",$a);
    $a = $a[0];
    $b = explode(" - ",$b);
    $b = $b[0];
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
}
usort($allStartDateTime, "sortFunction");
```